# Authorize an Org failed to run

Tags: salesforcedx

I'm trying to authorize my dev org via VS Code and it return error - 'Authorize and org failed to run'.

[image]

Any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 4):

I believe the problem is the space in `FI lwc`.
[image]

Having white space in the alias name is likely messing up the CLI arguments.

Either take the space out or try wrapping the alias with quotes. I'd probably stick with having no white space in the alias, as it will likely cause issues elsewhere.